# Implement SearchView inside recyclerview header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I wanted to add a `SearchView` to my `recyclerview`. I wanted it to be at the top and scrollable with the items. To achieve this, I created separate `adapter` for my `header` and it contains the `Searchview` as well. Then I used a `ConcatAdapter` to combine this `header` adapter with the contents below it.

Initially I want all the items to be visible under the `SearchView` from `_onBoardingState` which is a `MutableStateFlow` and when user searches for a `tag` then the results for it get added to `_onSearch` which is also a `MutableStateFlow`.

I have this `MutableStateFlow`, `_onBoardingState` inside my `ViewModel` that gets the value from `Firestore` in the `init` of `ViewModel`. The number of results is less (~ 20) so there is no `pagination` implemented and all items get loaded at once.

Now, whenever user wants to search an item by a `tag`, the `SearchView` returns a `Flow` of the typed value and also a `Flow` that updates about if the `SearchView` is still open or closed. I used these extension functions for this:

```
fun SearchView.getQueryTextChangeStateFlow(onSubmit: ()-> Unit): StateFlow<String> {

    val query = MutableStateFlow("")

    setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            onSubmit()
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            query.value = newText
            return true
        }
    })

    return query
}

fun SearchView.getActiveStateFlow(): StateFlow<Boolean> {

    val isOpen = MutableStateFlow(false)

    setOnSearchClickListener {

        isOpen.value = true
    }

    setOnCloseListener {

        isOpen.value = false
        false
    }

    return isOpen
}
```

Inside my `ViewModel` I have

```
...

private val _onBoardingState: MutableStateFlow<Model?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
private val _onSearch: MutableStateFlow<Model?> = MutableStateFlow(null)

private val _isActive: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)

fun toggleSearchViewState(isActive: Boolean) {

    _isActive.value = isActive
}

    val cuurentFlow: Flow<Model?> =
    _isActive.flatMapLatest { isActive ->

        if (isActive) {
            _onSearch
        } else {
            _onBoardingState
        }
    }

...
```

Now the issue here is, whenever the `recyclerview` is scrolled down, the `SearchView` gets recycled and hence the `setOnCloseListener`  gets called for it. This causes the `_isActive` value to be set to `false` by the `Header's Adapter` so the value of `cuurentFlow` gets toggled which should not be happening.

I thought of a solution as to set the `setOnCloseListener` of `SearchView` inside the `header` adapter's `onViewRecycled()` to `null`, but this didn't help. Below is code for my `Header Adapter` as well if needed.

```
class OnBoardingHeaderAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OnBoardingHeaderAdapter.HeaderViewHolder>() {

    private var queryTextListener: ((StateFlow<String>) -> Unit)? = null
    private var searchViewListener: ((StateFlow<Boolean>) -> Unit)? = null

    inner class HeaderViewHolder(binding: OnboardingHeaderItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        private val root = binding.headerRoot
        val search = binding.search

        fun bind(headerMetaData: HeaderMetaData) {

            root.visibility =

                if (headerMetaData.shouldShow)
                    View.VISIBLE
                else
                    View.GONE

            val searchEditText: EditText =
                search.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)

            searchEditText.setHintTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            searchEditText.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
        }
    }

    fun setQueryTextListener(listener: (StateFlow<String>) -> Unit) {

        this.queryTextListener = listener
    }

    fun setSearchViewListener(listener: (StateFlow<Boolean>) -> Unit) {

        this.searchViewListener = listener
    }

    private val RECYCLER_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<HeaderMetaData>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: HeaderMetaData, newItem: HeaderMetaData) =
            oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: HeaderMetaData, newItem: HeaderMetaData) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }

    val headerDiffer = AsyncListDiffer(this, RECYCLER_COMPARATOR)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HeaderViewHolder {

        val binding = OnboardingHeaderItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
        )

        return HeaderViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HeaderViewHolder, position: Int) {

        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false)

        if (position < 1) {

            val header = headerDiffer.currentList[position]
            holder.bind(header)
        }

        queryTextListener?.let {

            it(holder.search.getQueryTextChangeStateFlow() {

                val imm = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                val view: View  = holder.search

                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken,0)
            })
        }

        searchViewListener?.let {

            it(holder.search.getActiveStateFlow())
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = headerDiffer.currentList.size

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: HeaderViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)

        holder.search.setOnCloseListener(null)
    }

}
```

I wanted to know what is the best approach to solve this issue, I think even if i use a recyclerview with multiple view types here for the header then still the recycling issue will be there.

Comment: searchbar in recycler view in addition to search results is quite  complicated  and unnecessary to deal with. why can't you have a searchbar in cordinator layout or searchbar and recycler view both in a nested scrollview?

Comment: But as far as I know, a `recyclerview` should not be inside a `scrollview`

Comment: scrollview = a view that allows a list of views to be scrolled. recycler view = a view that allows a list of views to be recycled when scrolled. this is typically a use case for scrollview, where you don't want a particular view to be recycled . read more about `setNestedScrollingEnabled` and `setHasFixedSize` and you will realize scrollviews does have a mechanism to efficiently handle recyclerviews inside them . if this question gets a better alternative solution, then am all up for it.

Comment: okay, will try this approach